# Querying Firebase A/B testing using API

Tags: firebase, firebase-ab-testing

I'm writing a script that will generate extended A/B testing results. Is it possible to query Firebase A/B testing using API to get an experiment variant list, start date, end date, etc?

Answer (score 0):

There currently is no API to get/manage the list of experiments for [Firebase A/B testing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ab-testing). All management of experiments must be done through the Firebase console at the moment.

You might want to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/), and keep an eye out on the [Firebase blog](https://firebase.blog) and [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases) for changes.